# Prestashop - Add module to hook

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop

I want to transplant the module "blockviewed" to the hook displayFooterProduct.

Prestashop tells me this module can't be transplanted to that hook so I looked around and found this tutorial : http://docs.promokit.eu/doku.php/prestashophelp:hookmodule

It came out, I have to add some code in the blockviewed.php file.

I did my best and added this code at the end.

```
    public function hookdisplayFooterProduct($params) {
return $this->hookdisplayHeader('displayFooterProduct');
```

It doesn't work and crashes my backOffice, no wonder as I didn't completely grasp what I should put into that code.

Could you point me out what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `hookDisplayFooterProduct` not `hookdisplayFooterProduct` and you should use `hookRightColumn` instead of `hookdisplayHeader` (correctly `hookDisplayHeader`):

```
public function hookDisplayFooterProduct($params)
{
  return $this->hookRightColumn($params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Always nice to find support in this community ;)